# Tensorflow Object Detection API - Continuously Increasing RAM Usage during Training

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Environment:

- Tensorflow 1.8-gpu (official docker container)
- nVidia 1080ti GPU
- 64G RAM
- Input image size is only 300x300, and only 60 of them for testing

During training, observe the continuously increasing memory usage (from the "top" command)

- step-10 uses 39G
- step-200 uses 50G
- step-2000 use 59G
- ...
- OOM

Use the "ssd_mobilenet_v2" pipeline and reduce the batch-size, queue-size and input-reader.

Not sure why the memory usage is keep accumulating, then it becomes OOM. Is the system storing something other than the weights or there is a memory leak somewhere? The memory usage suppose to stay constant after several steps ?

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 2
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
  }
}

train_config {
  batch_size: 10
  num_steps: 200000
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  batch_queue_capacity: 10
  num_batch_queue_threads: 10
  prefetch_queue_capacity: 10
}

train_input_reader {
  queue_capacity: 10
  min_after_dequeue: 10
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 1
  max_evals: 10
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  queue_capacity: 10
  min_after_dequeue: 10
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this?  Having the same issue with mobilenet_v1_ssd - 50gb RAM usage after about 7k steps

Comment: Not yet... will revisit this issue later this week. Will keep updated here

Comment: Same problem here, the RAM usage is keep accumulating. Did you open an issue on their github repo?

Comment: @Jon No. I think we should. However, I am working on some other projects. Would you please help to do that?

Comment: github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5296

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a similar system. I solved it by experimenting with different tf and CUDA versions. What does your OOM crash error look like?

Your batch size is fine for a 1080 and 64 GB RAM.

One other thing I could recommend would be to try the v1 checkpoint.